# Let $f = \prod_{i=1}^n (X - z_i)^{r_i} \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. Prove that $\mathbb{C}[x]/(f) \simeq \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{C}[x]/(X-z_i)^{r_i}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-spaces

This exercise started asking to prove that there's a morphism between $R/(gh) \rightarrow R/(g) \times R/(h)$ and I proved that the canonical projection is in fact well defined there. Then it asked to find it's kernel, which I identified as the ideal generated by the  least common multiple of g and h.

So I was able to see that the kernel of the projection map between $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{C}[x]/(X-z_i)^{r_i}$ is indeed $f$. But now I have to see that it's actually an epimorphism and I'm having quite a bit of trouble there, and I'm not so sure it actually is.

Let's say I have $(\bar{p}_1,...,\bar{p}_n) \in \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{C}[x]/(X-z_i)^{r_i}$. I then should have a polynomial $P(x) = p_1(x) + (X-z_1)^{r_1}g_1(x) =\cdots= p_n(x) + (X-z_n)^{r_n}g_n(x)$, but I'm not sure how I would be able to construct it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can’t you just count dimensions?

Comment: I suppose $R=\mathbb C[x]$ and I think you should apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem.